# How to define custom code block syntax format in PhpStorm/JetBrains IDE?

Tags: templates, syntax, ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm working on a special php framework, which uses a special template block in the html template.

For example:

```
{if $a > 0}<!-- which depends on the context variable $a -->
<p {if $a < 10}class="lt10"{else}class="gt10"{/if}>
  <!-- embed the {if} tag inside a tag is also valid -->
  {$a}<!-- echo the context variable $a -->
</p>
{/if}
```

So, my PHPStorm highlights the content inside the tag as warning:

> Attribute {if is not allowed here.

So is there anyway to define the syntax of the custom code block correctly to make the IDE recognize my code format?

Comment: PhpStorm does not support such on-the-fly-custom-language-parsing. It has to be done via (custom) plugin that will parse such "language" into AST tokens (for syntax highlighting etc) and tell IDE that it's all good here. Alternatively -- use plugin that already supports such syntax (if there is one, of course).

Comment: @LazyOne Is there anyway to write one myself or is there any guide to do this?

Comment: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Plugin+Development 2) Have a look at existing plugins (custom languages/templating engines support) that are open sourced: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/phpStorm